# Is get_permalink also the canonical URL?

Tags: urls, permalinks

The question says it all. Does permalink equal canonical URL? Or is there another way to get the canonical URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are doing something weird with your URL structure (and maybe even then), the answer is **yes** according to [this blog post](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/).